# Proving that $n$ and $m$ divides $1^{n}+2^{n}+3^{n}+\cdots+m^{n}$

Tags: number-theory

For which positive integers $m, n$ is true that the number $$1^{n}+2^{n}+3^{n}+\cdots+m^{n}$$ is divisible by $n$ and $m$?

Comment: Check out Faulhaber's formula. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Example : n prime and m a multiple of n.

Comment: @user225222 Your suggestion does not work already for $n=2$, $m=2$.

Comment: n prime different than 2. Ah sorry i missed the divisble by m part.

Comment: @user225222 This still does not work. Set $n=3$, $m=6$.

Comment: @O.L. Yes i've already said : I'm sorry i've missed the divisble by m part. 
What is true is that : If $n\neq 2$  is prime and m is a multiple of n then n divdes $1^n+2^n+\cdots +m^n$.

Comment: @user225222 sorry, I didn't notice that you have edited your comment

Answer (score 2):

Here is some partial progress. If $n$ is square-free we can reduce your question to the following:

When do positive integers $n$ and $m$, with $n$ square-free, both divide $1+ 2 + \cdots + m = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$?

Let's start with the question of when a square-free positive integer $n$ divides the sum $1^n + 2^n + \cdots + m^n$. Factoring $n$ into primes, say we have $n = p_1\cdots p_r$, where the $p_i$ are distinct by hypothesis. Using the corollary to Fermat's Little Theorem we have $k^{p_i} \equiv k \ (\text{mod} \ p_i)$ for each $1 \le k \le m$ and for each prime $p_i$ dividing $n$. By repeated application of this we may conclude

$1^n + 2^n + \cdots + m^n \equiv 1+ 2 + \cdots + m \ (\text{mod} \ n)$,

from which we obtain the question I stated first. A question for you: why does $n$ have to be square free for the above argument to work in general?

We can go further with this line of reasoning. First off, $m$ must be odd. This is because if $m$ divides $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ then we find that $m+1=2k$ for some integer $k$.

Again, let's say $n = p_1\cdots p_r$, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes (so $n$ is square-free). This gives us a system of congruences. Put $x = 1 + 2 + \cdots + m$, we wish to solve

$x \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ p_i)$

simultaneously for each $i$. That is, we're solving for the prime numbers $p_i$, not for $x$. Let me remark, however, that if you fix a square free integer $n$, then the Chinese Remainder Theorem at least guarantees a solution, although it may not be terribly useful in finding those solutions.

Then by the above we can at least say $n$ is not even (again, provided we assume $n$ is square free). Moreover, we have a (trivial) upper bound on $n$. Namely if $n \neq \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$, then $n \le \frac{m(m+1)}{4}$.

Comment: You need the Chinese remainder theorem in there, somewhere, right?

Comment: Essentially yes. If $n$ is square free then what I've done above is very similar to an argument using CRT.

Comment: A counter example with $n$ not square free would be $n=45$, $m=6$, in which case we do not have $1^{45}+2^{45}+\cdots + 6^{45}$ congruent to $21$ modulo $45$. Rather, that sum is congruent to $36$ modulo $45$.